# how I can make a gradient in the center of a button horizontally

Tags: css

hello I wanted to know how I can make a gradient in the center of a button horizontally, I leave an image of how I want to do it but with css code.
Thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5ys9.png)

Comment: Can you include the CSS code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `background` property in css

```css
button {
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  border: none;

  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(180,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(180,1,1,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<button>FREE INVESTOR KIT</button>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much :)

Comment: You're weolcome @matigcba, if that answers your question you can mark this answer as correct.